# MVC Return Json result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have a controller that uploads a file. I would like to return a json result with bool success (if successfully uploaded otherwise false) and message (this could be error message that occured OR link to a file OR link to an image, depending on what was uploaded).

What's the best way to approach this?

I have this

```
public class UploadedFile
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

then In my controller I would set Success to true/or/false and Message to `<a href` OR `<img`

am i on the right track?

How would i then parse this in the view so that when image it will show an image, if link show a link, if error simply alert error.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to parse it ? Can't you provide more information in what you return in Json ?

Maybe something like that :

```
public class UploadedFile
{
  public bool Success { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
  public Kind MessageKind { get; set; }
}

public enum Kind
{
  Error,
  File,
  Image
}
```

Depending on the `MessageKind`, you'll just have to use proper html to display the result.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track. I would recommend you using the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) which would allow you to AJAXify the `<form>` and handle the success case.

Example:

Model:

```
public class UploadedFile
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var images = Server.MapPath("~/images");
            var filename = Path.Combine(images, Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
            file.SaveAs(filename);
            return View("UploadedFile", new UploadedFile
            {
                Success = true,
                Url = Url.Content("~/images/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName))
            });
        }
        return View("UploadedFile", new UploadedFile
        {
            Success = false,
            Message = "Please upload a file"
        });
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.form.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form').ajaxForm(function (result) {
            $('#result').html(result);
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

<div id="result"></div>
```

and the UploadedFile partial:

```
@model AppName.Models.UploadedFile
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@if (Model.Success)
{
    <img src="@Model.Url" alt="" />
} else {
    @Model.Message
}
```